# Can any planar graph be extended into a bipartite planar graph by a series of operations?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

The **edge subdivision operation** for an edge $\{u,v\}∈E$ is the deletion of $\{u,v\}$ from $G$ and the addition of two edges $\{u,w\}$ and $\{w,v\}$ along with the new vertex $w$.

My  first question is as follows:

**Can any planar graph be extended into a bipartite planar graph by a series of subdivision operations?**

My initial idea was based on an equivalent description of  bipartite graph.

- A graph is bipartite if and only if it does not contain an odd cycle.

For any odd cycle, we can subdivide one of the edges to get an even cycle. But it seems possible to create some new odd cycle, as illustrated below.

[image]

So I'm wondering if we can eliminate all odd cycles with limited subdivision operations.

---

**Edits**:  **In the comments, Manuel Lafond  answers above question. But I have another problem.**

A planar graph $G$ which contains at least a 4-face, can we get a bipartite graph by subdividing edges in the condition of **keeping all  4-faces**?

We are allowed to subdivide edges **other than** any edges of  the boundaries of all 4-faces. Now subdivision alone may not be enough to modify the original graph into a bipartite graph. for example,  the triangle in the following graph  cannot be  eliminated by edge subdivision.

[image: ![enter image description here]

So **we're allowed to add new vertices and edges .** We also hope to get a bipartite planar graph.  But one prerequisite is that we do not destroy the 4-face.

---

PS:  The original problem came from the proof of the following theorem.

**Theorem 1.** [a] For any graph $H$, there is an optimal 1-planar graph having a topological minor of $H$.

[a] Suzuki Y. K7-minors in optimal 1-planar graphs[J]. Discrete Mathematics, 2017, 340(6): 1227-1234.

Comment: If you subdivide every edge, the graph will be bipartite - in one part, put the vertices from the original graph and in the other part, the vertices created by the subdivisions.  If you want to minimize the number of subdivisions, this answer might help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/251158/minimum-modifications-to-make-a-graph-bipartite.  It's a max-cut problem on planar graphs.

Comment: Very interesting. I see what you mean. My problem is actually a little bit more complicated. We had this limitation: four edges of  any 4-face of the planar graph could not be subdivided.  I'm going to edit this  question.

Comment: You can draw a chord to make each 4-cycle into two 3-cycles, and then use Manuel's method, no?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I actually want to keep  all these 4-faces, and then I want to get a bipartite planar graph by adding vertices and edges or edge subdividing on the  original planar graph.

Comment: I wish you'd make up your mind as to what exactly you want. I'll come back in a day or two, to see what other conditions you've come up with.

Comment: Thank you for your attention.  Sorry for the confusion caused by my modification problem. But I think my qualifications are complete enough. This is a problem that I just came across in the paper reading the proof of theorem 1. [Suzuki Y. K7-minors in optimal 1-planar graphs[J]. Discrete Mathematics, 2017, 340(6): 1227-1234. ]  And I pulled it out for discussion. I was surprised by the author's proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not necessarily possible.

Suppose there is an odd face $F$, such that each adjacent face is a square, so you cannot subdivide edges of $F$. Then you are asking to add inside $F$ an arbitrary planar graph $H$, such that $F + H$ is bipartite. In $F + H$, the outer face is odd, while any inner face is even. Thus its dual graph has exactly one odd-degree vertex, which is impossible.

Comment: A simple example is a triangular prism.